# Why is the complexity of std::unordered_set operator==() N^2?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, comparison-operators, unordered-set

I have two vectors `v1` and `v2` of type `std::vector<std::string>`. Both vectors have unique values and should compare equal if values compare equal but independent of the order values appear in the vector.

I assume two sets of type `std::unordered_set` would have been a better choice, but I take it as it is, so two vectors.

Nevertheless, I thought for the needed order insensitive comparison I'll just use `operator==` from `std::unordered_set` by copying to two `std::unordered_set`. Very much like this:

```cpp
bool oi_compare1(std::vector<std::string> const&v1,
                 std::vector<std::string> const&v2)
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> tmp1(v1.begin(),v1.end());
    std::unordered_set<std::string> tmp2(v2.begin(),v2.end());
    return tmp1 == tmp2;
}
```

While profiling I noticed this function consuming a lot of time, so I checked doc and saw the `O(n*n)` complexity here. I am confused, I was expecting `O(n*log(n))`, like e.g. for the following naive solution I came up with:

```cpp
bool oi_compare2(std::vector<std::string> const&v1,
                 std::vector<std::string> const&v2)
{
    if(v1.size() != v2.size())
        return false;
    auto tmp = v2;
    size_t const size = tmp.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        for(size_t j = i; j < size; ++j)
            if(v1[i] == tmp[j]){
                flag = true;
                std::swap(tmp[i],tmp[j]);
                break;
            }
        if(!flag)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why the `O(n*n)` complexity for `std::unordered_set` and is there a build in function I can use for order insensitive comparision?

EDIT----
BENCHMARK

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool oi_compare1(std::vector<std::string> const&v1,
        std::vector<std::string> const&v2)
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> tmp1(v1.begin(),v1.end());
    std::unordered_set<std::string> tmp2(v2.begin(),v2.end());
    return tmp1 == tmp2;
}
bool oi_compare2(std::vector<std::string> const&v1,
                std::vector<std::string> const&v2)
{
    if(v1.size() != v2.size())
        return false;
    auto tmp = v2;
    size_t const size = tmp.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        for(size_t j = i; j < size; ++j)
            if(v1[i] == tmp[j]){
                flag = true;
                std::swap(tmp[i],tmp[j]);
                break;
            }
        if(!flag)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> s1{"1","2","3"};
    std::vector<std::string> s2{"1","3","2"};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        auto tmp1 = s1;
        for(auto &iter : tmp1)
            iter = std::to_string(i)+iter;
        s1.insert(s1.end(),tmp1.begin(),tmp1.end());
        s2.insert(s2.end(),tmp1.begin(),tmp1.end());
    }
    std::cout << "size1 " << s1.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size2 " << s2.size() << std::endl;

    for(auto && c : {oi_compare1,oi_compare2})
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        bool flag = true;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            flag = flag && c(s1,s2);
        std::cout << "ms=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count() << " flag=" << flag << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
size1 98304
size2 98304
ms=844 flag=true
ms=31 flag=true
```

--> naive approach way faster.

For all the Complexity O(N*N) experts here...
Let me go through this naive approach. I have two loops there. The first loop is running from `i=0` to size which is N. The inner loop is called from j=i!!!!!! to N. In language spoken it means I call the Inner loop N times. But the complexity of the inner loop is log(n) due to the starting index of j = i !!!!. If you still dont believe me calculate the complexity from benchmarks and you will see...

EDIT2---
LIVE ON WANDBOX
https://wandbox.org/permlink/v26oxnR2GVDb9M6y

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185713/discussion-on-question-by-oz17-why-is-the-complexity-of-stdunordered-set-opera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, your benchmark of `operator==` is faulty.

`oi_compare1` accepts 2 vectors and needs to build up 2 complete `unordered_set` instances, to than call `operator==` and destroy the complete bunch again.

`oi_compare2` also accepts 2 vectors, and immediately uses them for the comparison on size. Only copies 1 instance (v2 to tmp), which is much more performant for a vector.

### operator==

Looking at the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp we can see the expected complexity:

> Proportional to N calls to operator== on value_type, calls to the predicate returned by key_eq, and calls to the hasher returned by hash_function, in the average case, proportional to N2 in the worst case where N is the size of the container.

**edit**
There is a simple algorithm, you can loop over the `unordered_set` and do a simple lookup in the other one. Without hash collisions, it will find each element in it's own internal bucket and compare it for equality as the hashing ain't sufficient.

<strike>Assuming you don't have hash collisions, each element of the `unordered_set` has a stable order in which they are stored. One could loop over the internal buckets and compare the elements 2-by-2 (1st of the one with the 1st of the second, 2nd of the one with the 2nd of the second ...). This nicely gives `O(N)`.</strike> *This doesn't work when you have different sizes of the buckets you store the values in, or when the assignment of buckets uses a different calculation to deal with collisions.*

Assuming you are unlucky and every element results into the same hash. (Known as `hash flooding`) You result in a list of elements without order. To compare, you have to check for each element if it exists in the other one, causing `O(N*N)`.

This last one is easy reproducible if you rig your hash to always return the same number. Build the one set in the reverse order as the other one.

Comment: Yes the benchmark is faulty mainly because I did not shuffle the vectors. However I added the benchmark afterwards, question was originally only about the algorithm complexities itself. Thank you for that!!! One last thing, so I assume collision probability is practically 0 and it almost always gives `O(n)` and even if it happens to give collisions and `O(n*n)`, theoretically I could simply switch to a different hash with less collision probabilities and get back to `O(n)` and be better performant than with the naive approach `O(n*log(n))`, right?

Comment: `O(n*n)` has to do with the algorithm used. Yes, you could change hashing, recompile and redeploy. However, is that possible for big applications that need to be up 100% of the time?    If you have control about your data, just keep the data sorted in a vector and you always have `O(N)` for compare at the cost of insertion/removal.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: The statement in this answer that you could "loop over the internal vector and compare the elements 2x2" is incorrect.  vxst's answer is correct.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Tnx for pointing this out, I've took an oversimplified model to reason about. I've updated the answer. Always a pleasure learning from someone who implemented those libcxx classes

Answer (score 5):

Since unordered_set is build using hashmap, the logic to compare lhs==rhs will be:

- Check size of lhs and rhs, if not equal, return false
- For each item in lhs, find it in rhs, and compare

For hashmap, the single find time complexity for an item in rhs in worst case will be O(n). So the worst case time complexity will be O(n^2). However normally you get an time complexity of O(n).

Comment: Yeah thats ok, but you can simply hack your second point to be more efficient thats why i am confused. Remove the elements of the rhs which you already compared to equal. So You then have ---> For each item in lhs, find it in rhs where rhs size is size - already compared equal to true elements. (reason why you can do this is because elements are unique...) makes it from O(n*n) to O(n*log(n)). Am I wrong?

Comment: @OZ17 Yes, you are wrong. It still is `O(n^2)`, just like `1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)`.

Comment: To make it absolute O(n lgn), you can first create two arrays from lhs and rhs, sort them, and do a linear scan. However the memory allocation overhead will be huge and normally you will get a much slower version of "=="

Comment: @vxst Very good point. I am basically doing this but I sort while making the comparision. So I just have one temporary vector, instead of 2. Do you think they did not want to hurt memory complexity (temporary vectors) and therefore chose to go with the slower time complexity (N*N) solution?

Comment: @OZ17 "They" didn't choose anything. The `O(n^2)` worst-case complexity is inherent to the very concept of a hashset.